# How do I get my Collection to use a different DB connection?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, collection

So I have extended a Magento collection to obtain my own collection only I want to use a different DB connection.  What I have attempted to do is define the connection in **config.xml** like so:

```
<global>
    <resources>
        <externaldb_write>
            <connection>
                <use>externaldb_database</use>
            </connection>
        </externaldb_write>
        <externaldb_read>
            <connection>
                <use>externaldb_database</use>
            </connection>
        </externaldb_read>
        <externaldb_setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </externaldb_setup>
        <externaldb_database>
            <connection>
                <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
                <username><![CDATA[db_username]]></username>
                <password><![CDATA[db_password]]></password>
                <dbname><![CDATA[db_name]]></dbname>
                <model>mysql4</model>
                <type>pdo_mysql</type>
                <active>1</active>
            </connection>
        </externaldb_database>
    </resources>
</global>
```

and then in my overriding constructor, do:

```
class VMR_Customreports_Model_Resource_Storeoverview_Collection extends     Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Order_Collection
{
        public function __construct()
        {
                parent::__construct();

                $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
                $conn = $resource->getConnection('externaldb_read');

                $this->setConnection($conn);
        }
.....
}
```

This doesn't appear to have any effect.  I would have expected an error if it didn't work.  What do I do?

UPDATE: After more debugging, I note that this code below returns the original db connection and not the one I defined in my XML.  Why is that?

`$conn = $resource->getConnection('externaldb_read');`

Comment: Is the collection class based on `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract` or `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract`?

Comment: My Collection extends Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Order_Collection.  One sec and I'll try to dig down to see if it extends from either of those.

Comment: It extends from Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick check (see test case below) actually shows what you are doing should be just peachy.
For that reason, I suspect some error in your configuration.
Please edit your post to include your collection class with at least it's `__construct` and `_construct` methods.
Also, if you are not using the `sales/order` resource model, please include it with it's constructor methods, too.

**UPDATE:**
I just noticed you are using `$resource->getConnection('reportingdb_read');` in your constructor.
In the configuration XML the connection is called `<externaldb_read>`.
Note: `reportingdb_read`  != `externaldb_read`

Maybe thats just a copy & paste error in your post, but if not, you have to use
`$resource->getConnection('externaldb_read');`
If that isn't the issue, please update your post, again, and I'll help dig further.

---

```
// Test to confirm a connection set via setConnection() on a 
// Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Order_Collection instance is used
// to load the collection data.
class Reports_CollectionTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public static function setUpBeforeClass()
    {
        require_once 'app/Mage.php';
        Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
        Mage::app('admin');
    }

    protected function getConnectionMock()
    {
        $mockSelect = $this->getMockBuilder('Varien_Db_Select')
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();

        $mockConn = $this->getMockBuilder('Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql')
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();

        $mockConn->expects($this->once())
            ->method('select')
            ->will($this->returnValue($mockSelect));

        $mockConn->expects($this->once())
            ->method('fetchAll');

        return $mockConn;
    }

    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function testCollectionConnection()
    {
        $mockCon = $this->getConnectionMock();

        $collection = new Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Order_Collection;
        $collection->setConnection($mockCon);

        $this->assertSame($mockCon, $collection->getConnection());
        $collection->load();
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated my original post to include the whole constructor.  As far as I know I am using the sales/order resource model because I am just rewriting the query but still using the order table.  If there's something else you need, please let me know.  Thank you.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Yeah sorry, that isn't the issue.  I just didnt copy properly.  I updated the OP.  Please continue to help me.

Comment: Also, having done a bit of debbugging, it looks like my collection's $this->_conn doesn't change upon calling $this->setCollection()