# Use External Database for a Custom Collection

Tags: database, collection, magento-1

I've been following this thread but I couldn't get it to work, [How do I get my Collection to use a different DB connection?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/11224/how-do-i-get-my-collection-to-use-a-different-db-connection).

I'm trying to load a collection from an external database separate from the main magento database.

config.xml:

```
<otherdb_setup>
    <connection>
        <host><![CDATA[127.0.0.1]]></host>
        <username><![CDATA[root]]></username>
        <password><![CDATA[]]></password>
        <dbname><![CDATA[otherdb]]></dbname>
        <model>mysql4</model>
        <initstatements>SET NAMES utf8</initstatements>
        <type>pdo_mysql</type>
        <active>1</active>
    </connection>
</otherdb_setup>
<otherdb_write>
    <connection>
        <use>otherdb_setup</use>
    </connection>
</otherdb_write>
<otherdb_read>
    <connection>
        <use>otherdb_setup</use>
    </connection>
</otherdb_read>
```

Then on my collection file (`class Custom_Module_Model_Mysql4_Mod_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract`):

```
public function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('custom_module/mod');

    $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
    $conn = $resource->getConnection('otherdb_read');

    $this->setConnection($conn);
}
```

I'm stuck on this part.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a loiok at `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product` for an example, you will see that they use `__construct()`:

```
/**
 * Initialize resource
 */
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setType(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY)
         ->setConnection('catalog_read', 'catalog_write');
    // ...
```

I suggest you emulate that in your model:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent:__construct();
    $this->setConnection('otherdb_read', 'otherdb_write');
}
```

I'd also suggest you implement the unit test that Vinai provided as an example into your framework to ensure it's configured correctly for you.